# Coloring a specific row ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colors, row, activeadmin

Hi I'm working with Ruby on Rails and ActiveAdmin, in my webpage I have a table, and if a value of that table becomes negative I want that specific row becomes red. I was reading about CodeRay before but it seems is only for color the rows in the file not the rows in the table.

Any idea about how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all set the CSS colour in a file under `/app/assets/stylesheets/`

```
.bg-red { background-color: red; } # or a nicer shade of red
```

Then in your table:

```
<tr class="#{"red" if object.value < 0}">
  <td><%= object.attribute1 %></td>
  <td><%= object.attribute2 %></td>
</tr>
```

So if your object's value is less than 0 (negative), `"red"` will be output to the class of that `tr`, otherwise nothing will be added to it.